# How to trim strings in AppleScript?

Tags: string, applescript, subdirectory

I am trying to trim a returned string in AppleScript. It's the directory of the script within the app I packaged it in. The idea is to make this app mobile as the old one relied on a static directory to run a script within another app, Spore_origin.app, contained within it's app package. Here's the code:

```
to run
    set current_path to POSIX path of (path to me) as string    
    tell application "Terminal"
        do script current_path & "/Spore_origin.app/Contents/MacOS/cider_noui"
    end tell    
end run
```

What I want to do is trim this off the end:

/Users/mypetnamedsteve/Stuff/Spore.app/Contents/Resources/Scripts/`main.scpt`

The Highlighted bit needs trimming but I don't know how. HeLp!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just get the parent folder. No need to use string manipulation

```
set current_path to (POSIX path of (container of (path to me))) as string
```

depending on the type of path - if you get a hfs path this will also work

```
set current_path to POSIX path of ((path to me as text) & "::")
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm really new to this and I just want the damn buggy program to work (they discontinued support for it years ago).

Comment: Not answering "How to trim strings" though.

Answer (score 1):

For actually **trimming the string** *(and thus being applicable for other situations where you need to trim strings, which* is *the headline of the question)*

Code for trimming a string having a `~/` prefix, or a `/~` suffix:

```
set example_string to "~/Wow/~"
-- prefix
if example_string starts with "~/" then
    set music_folder to characters (count of "~/") thru -1 of example_string as string
    -- instead of (count of "~/") you could just use 2
end if
-- suffix
if example_string ends with "/" then
    set example_string to characters -1 - (count of "/~") thru -1 of example_string as string
    -- instead of -1 - (count of "~/") you could just use -3
end if
```

Answer (score 0):

```
set myPath to POSIX path of (path to me)
tell application "Terminal"
    do script ("`dirname " & quoted form of myPath & "`/Spore_origin.app/Contents/MacOS/cider_noui")
end tell
```